# ARCore Multi image tracking

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I usually develop AR with Vuforia through unity, but started messing around with ARCore recently. I have done a bunch of stuff with Face Recognition, and some minigames. When I finally tried to do simple image track I had no problem with it, but then struggled to find a way to put different prefabs on different images. I've tried a few solutions that I found online with no success.

I came across this code last night and wanted to give it a shot.

I assign different prefabs to different images by this way:

> I modified the AugmentedImageExampleController.cs:.
>   I added a list for prefabs:
>
> ```
> public List<AugmentedImageVisualizer> prefabs = new List<AugmentedImageVisualizer>();
> ```
>
> For the related image for the prefab I did a reference by using the image.DatabaseIndex in the visualizer:
>
> ```
> visualizer = (AugmentedImageVisualizer)Instantiate(prefabs[image.DatabaseIndex], anchor.transform);
> ```
>
> In the inspector of ExampleController you can put in the prefabs (AugmentedImageVisualizer) now.
>
> That's it, and its working fine!

Does anyone know where this piece of the code would be implemented??

```
visualizer = (AugmentedImageVisualizer)Instantiate(prefabs[image.DatabaseIndex], anchor.transform);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so we have a better reference point to where it might go?

Comment: I found a solution for it lastnight. I'm currently at a meeting, but will post it when I get back for anyone else that might need help. I ended up taking a different approach, but it worked!

Comment: Hi @JHavok, I hope you arrived safely when you got home. I've been waiting for your answer since 2019.